# How do I change the max.print option in R's summary?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, descriptive-statistics

I'm estimating a GLM with a bunch of parameters in R.

When I run this:

```
  M <- glm( Y ~ factor(X1) + factor(X2) )   
  summary(M)
```

R only gives me part of the table, then cuts out with the message:

```
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 621 rows ]]
```

The summary table will be big, but I want the whole thing.  How do I change the max.print option?  I've tried several different versions and nothing works.

Edit: Here's another attempt which gives me a different error.

```
summary(M, options(max.print=100000))
Error in dispersion * covmat.unscaled : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just googled "R getOption("max.print")", and found: `options(max.print=5.5E5)`...

Comment: I found that too, but where do I put it?  Before the summary() call?  Inside it?  I tried both and it still won't show the whole table.

Comment: Most certainly before it. First you run `options(max.print=5.5E5)`, then you run `summary(M)`. Note of course that you may need to alter the value 5.5E5 to your needs. Although I hope you really don't want to print 550000 lines and hope to get something out of it. It may be worth checking the value after you have set it by running `getOption("max.print")` after setting it.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `sink`. This will divert output to a file, which then you can inspect.

```
sink(file="output.txt")
summary(M)
sink(NULL)
```

The error you get in your code is because the second argument of function `summary.glm` is `dispersion`, which according to help page should be either numeric or NULL. You supply the output of `options(max.print=100000)` which is not what R expects, hence the error.